# How to use the stockfish chess engine in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, chess

Recently I created an android chess app (using Android Studio) that allows playing human vs human. Now I am trying to use the stockfish chess engine to play human vs computer.

***Note:** I have enough knowledge about **Java**, **C++**, **SDK**, and **NDK**.*

**The problem:** I download stockfish for android from https://stockfishchess.org/download/. I get all source files (*.cpp and .h*). But there is no documentation on how to use the files and which method/function I need invoke for which activity. I don't find any document about the stockfish source code. I also see [the Droidfish](https://github.com/peterosterlund2/droidfish) source code on the GitHub. But It's very difficult to understand the stockfish activity in that source code.

> Do there any document for stockfish or any tutorial?

***What do I want to do?** I want to pass the board position to stockfish for the best move/moves in this position.*

Comment: The stockfish download page mentions UCI, maybe this can help you along? https://www.chessprogramming.org/UCI

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I hope so UCI can help me.